# If statement function Hiding form inputs based on element value, How do I make it shorter?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I have a large chunk of javascript that hides and shows inputs based on the element being selected, I want to reduce the number of else ifs I need to use in this case. Basically anyway I can shorten this code would be good.

```
    function routerChange(element) {
         if ((element.value == '****') || (element.value == '****')){
            $('.network_hide').show();
            $('.net_password_hide').show();
            $('.activation_hide').show();
            $('.telephone_hide').show();
            $('.ip_address_hide').show();
            $('.ppp_username_hide').hide();
            $('.ppp_password_hide').hide();
            $('.lan_ip_hide').hide();
            $('.subnet_mask_hide').hide();
        } else if (element.value == '2862N_DTG'){
            $('.network_hide').hide();
            $('.net_password_hide').hide();
            $('.activation_hide').hide();
            $('.telephone_hide').hide();
            $('.ip_address_hide').hide();
            $('.ppp_username_hide').show();
            $('.ppp_password_hide').show();
            $('.lan_ip_hide').show();
            $('.subnet_mask_hide').show();
             $('#PPP').show();
        } else if ((element.value == '****') || (element.value == '****') || (element.value == '****') || (element.value == '****')){
            $('.network_hide').show();
            $('.net_password_hide').show();
            $('.activation_hide').show();
            $('.telephone_hide').show();
            $('.ip_address_hide').hide();
             $('.ppp_username_hide').hide();
             $('.ppp_password_hide').hide();
             $('.lan_ip_hide').hide();
             $('.subnet_mask_hide').hide();
        } else if (element.value == '****'){
            $('.network_hide').hide();
            $('.net_password_hide').hide();
            $('.activation_hide').show();
            $('.telephone_hide').show();
            $('.ip_address_hide').hide();
             $('.ppp_username_hide').hide();
             $('.ppp_password_hide').hide();
             $('.lan_ip_hide').hide();
             $('.subnet_mask_hide').hide();
        } else if ((element.value == '****') || (element.value == '****') || (element.value == '****')){
            $('.network_hide').show();
            $('.net_password_hide').show();
            $('.activation_hide').hide();
            $('.telephone_hide').hide();
            $('.ip_address_hide').hide();
             $('.ppp_username_hide').hide();
             $('.ppp_password_hide').hide();
             $('.lan_ip_hide').hide();
             $('.subnet_mask_hide').hide();
        } else if (element.value == '****'){
            $('.network_hide').hide();
            $('.net_password_hide').hide();
            $('.activation_hide').hide();
            $('.telephone_hide').hide();
            $('.ip_address_hide').hide();
             $('.ppp_username_hide').hide();
             $('.ppp_password_hide').hide();
             $('.lan_ip_hide').hide();
             $('.subnet_mask_hide').hide();
        } else {
            $('.network_hide').show();
            $('.net_password_hide').show();
            $('.activation_hide').show();
            $('.telephone_hide').show();
            $('.ip_address_hide').show();
            $('.ppp_username_hide').hide();
            $('.ppp_password_hide').hide();
            $('.lan_ip_hide').hide();
            $('.subnet_mask_hide').hide();
        }
            }
```

Just to be clear this code works as intended, I just want to reduce its size.

Comment: Just wrap everything inside a div and hide/show those divs.

Comment: You can invert the relationship - instead of this showing/hiding the components, you can have *the components* watch for relevant changes and show/hide themselves. Then your components would be responding to the state, instead of you having to manage each one individually. However, that would be easier done using some framework or template engine that supports binding to data. You can also do it yourself, but no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: What the idea behind this: `(element.value == '****') || (element.value == '****')` Its same check multiple times

Comment: Rajesh they are different element values I just didn't want to show them for privacy reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use an array of objects, with properties: (1) a function to invoke, which, if it returns true: (2) hides all selectors in a `hide` array (3) shows all selectors in a `show` array. For example:

```
const conditions = [
  {
    fn: value => value == '****' || value == '****',
    show: ['network_hide', 'net_password_hide', 'activation_hide', 'telephone_hide', 'ip_address_hide'],
    hide: ['ppp_username_hide', 'ppp_password_hide', 'lan_ip_hide', 'subnet_mask_hide']
  },
  {
    fn: value => value === '2862N_DTG',
    show: ...
  }
  ...
];
// For the final else:
const defaults = {
  show: ['network_hide', 'net_password_hide', 'activation_hide', 'telephone_hide', 'ip_address_hide'],
  hide: ['ppp_username_hide', 'ppp_password_hide', 'lan_ip_hide', 'subnet_mask_hide']
};
```

Then `.find` the first condition that passes, or use the `defaults` object if none pass:

```
function routerChange(element) {
  const { value } = element;
  const found = conditions.find(cond => cond.fn(value)) || defaults;
  found.show.forEach(classToShow => $('.' + classToShow).show());
  found.hide.forEach(classToHide => $('.' + classToHide).hide());
}
```

It would be possible to minify it further, but it would probably come at the expense of readability, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Not very smart solution but u can try this way it will reduce pretty enough code

```
function routerChange(element) {
    if ((element.value == '****') || (element.value == '****')){   
        check(true, true, true, true, true, false, false, false, false)
    } else if (element.value == '2862N_DTG'){
       // call check again 
    } else if ((element.value == '****') || (element.value == '****') || (element.value == '****') || (element.value == '****')){
        // call check again 
    } else if (element.value == '****'){

    } else if ((element.value == '****') || (element.value == '****') || (element.value == '****')){
       // call check again 
    } else if (element.value == '****'){
       // call check again 
    } else {
        // call check again 
    }
}

function check(nh, np, ah, th, ia, pu, pp, li, sm) {
  nh === true ? $('.network_hide').show() :  $('.network_hide').hide();
  np === true ? $('.net_password_hide').show() : $('.net_password_hide').hide();
  ah === true ? $('.activation_hide').show():  $('.activation_hide').hide();
  th === true ? $('.telephone_hide').show():  $('.telephone_hide').hide();
  ia === true ? $('.ip_address_hide').show():  $('.ip_address_hide').hide();
  pu === true ? $('.ppp_username_hide').hide():  $('.ppp_username_hide').hide();
  pp === true ? $('.ppp_password_hide').hide():  $('.ppp_password_hide').hide();
  li === true ? $('.lan_ip_hide').hide():  $('.lan_ip_hide').hide();
  sm === true ? $('.subnet_mask_hide').hide():  $('.subnet_mask_hide').hide();
}
```